# How can I send a form with custom headers

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a `GET` api endpoint to download a CSV file:

`GET /api/v1/reports/report.csv`

- It has two parameters: `start_date` and `end_date`
- It will check the `api-key` in the header of the request.

So I can use postman to send `GET` request with api-key in headers to download the file.

---

Now there is a form in website. User can enter the `start_date` and `end_date` and press the `Download`(submit) button.

My question is, how can I insert the `api-key` in the header of the request?

Comment: You can't add headers to standard form submissions through HTML. You can do it through an AJAX request, but that won't enable you to download the file. Assuming you control the server holding the CSV content you would need to add the `api-key` value as a querystring argument.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to make your API more suitable for browsers and pass api-key in get-parameter or in cookies.

Other option is to download file via ajax (this will not show download progress etc), a hidden anchor element will be needed:

```
<a id="stubAnchor" style="display: none"></a>
```

And js:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "/api/v1/reports/report.csv", true);
req.responseType = "blob";
req.setRequestHeader('Api-key', 'some_key')

req.onload = function (event) {
  var blob = req.response;
  var fileName = "report.csv";
  var contentType = req.getResponseHeader("content-type");

  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    // IE
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob([blob], {type: contentType}), fileName);
  } else {
    var el = document.getElementById("stubAnchor");
    el.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    el.download = fileName;
    el.click();
  }
};
req.send();
```